# Display a List of entities in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to display a `List<Student>` using JSF.

```
public List<Student> retrieveStudent()
{
Sdao sdao=new Sdao();
List<Student> stud=new ArrayList();
List sname1=new ArrayList();
List sdept1=new ArrayList();
for(Student show1:sdao.retrieveStudent())
{

    sname1.add(show1.getSname());
    sdept1.add(show1.getSdept());

}
stud.addAll(sname1);
stud.addAll(sdept1);


return stud;

}
```

JSF Page:

```
    <h:form>

        <h:outputText value="#{student.retrieveStudent()}"/>
     </h:form>
```

Output:

```
[Alpha,Beta,Science,Electronics]
```

I want to print it in a table with column name Names(Alpha, Beta) and column 2 their departments..i am not sure how to separate them and print...can anyone help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, convention for this cases is to create an attribute in the **bean** not in the `Student.java` class. Also you must have a method called `getNameOfAttribute()` to use in the view (in this case `getStudents()`).

---

What you see in the output: `[Alpha,Beta,Science,Electronics]` is the `toString()` representation of the `stud` List retrieved by `retrieveStudent()` method.

What you have to do is put this list in [`DataTable`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_display_datatable.htm):

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userData.retrieveStudent()}" var="student" >
   <h:column>                   
      <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>                 
      #{student.name}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Department</f:facet>
      #{student.department}
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**NOTE:** student must implement public methods `getName()` and `getDeparment()`.

Comment: As you said i created attribute in Bean and tried and it worked! thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: great to hear you tried and succeed!! is not only to make things work, also use better practices to improve our programming skills :)